# be invisible to one particular user in Pidgin

Tags: pidgin, yahoo-messenger

Is there any way to be invisible to just one user on my Pidgin buddy list, and visible to everyone else? It is a Yahoo Messenger user in case that matters.

Comment: Is there not a block? (on right click or in settings, think there used to be)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just right click on the name and select "Presence Settings" > "Appear permanently offline"

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I failed to notice this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Pidgin can't do anything that the underlying protocol doesn't support. If Y!IM can't do it then Pidgin won't be able to.

Comment: Yahoo Messenger has a "Appear permanently offline to this user" option in the stealth settings for each user. Is there any way to access this option in Pidgin?

Answer (score -1):

install pidgin-gtalkinvisible
"Invisible status for Google Talk protocol in Pidgin"  from synaptic